# start a .exe in the background with parameters in a powershell script

Tags: powershell, jobs, job-scheduling

I have a programm which i usually start like this in powershell:

```
.\storage\bin\storage.exe -f storage\conf\storage.conf
```

What is the correct syntax for calling it in the background? I tried many combinations like:

```
start-job -scriptblock{".\storage\bin\storage.exe -f storage\conf\storage.conf"}
start-job -scriptblock{.\storage\bin\storage.exe} -argumentlist "-f", "storage\conf\storage.conf"
```

but without success. Also it should run in a powershell script.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The job will be another instance of PowerShell.exe and it will not start in same path so `.` won't work. It needs to know where `storage.exe` is.

Also you have to use the arguments from argumentlist in the scriptblock. You can either use the built-in args array or do named parameters. The args way needs the least amount of code.

```
$block = {& "C:\full\path\to\storage\bin\storage.exe" $args}
start-job -scriptblock $block -argumentlist "-f", "C:\full\path\to\storage\conf\storage.conf"
```

Named parameters are helpful to know what what arguments are supposed to be. Here's how it would look using them:

```
$block = {
    param ([string[]] $ProgramArgs)
    & "C:\full\path\to\storage\bin\storage.exe" $ProgramArgs
}
start-job -scriptblock $block -argumentlist "-f", "C:\full\path\to\storage\conf\storage.conf"
```

Comment: How would the named parameter version look like? I am already using $args for calling the script, so I can't use the args array.

Comment: You can still use args. It has a new scope in the scriptblock (and it will be used in another instance of powershell.exe for the job) but I updated to show named parameters.

Comment: Ah Ok. Now I have run into another problem. You might know this one too? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15769126/expand-variable-in-block